# Feed a Flex4 application from WCF

Tags: wcf, apache-flex, flex4

First of all i have to admit i'm new to the world of Flex.

So my question is this: in a Flex 4 application photos and videos have to be shown. Is it wise to use a WCF service to feed the application or should the photos/videos loaded in another way? Is the WCF service fast enough to send data to the app? Can it handle the "stream" for small videos (around 2 min)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on articles and my experiments i conclude that it is not very wise to use a .NET WCF service to feed the Flex Application. 
The preferred solution is to use a tool like FLuorineFX (completely free) or WebORB(with limitations).